# Replicating columns in dataframe based on the column names

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a following `dataframe` called ol_axle:

| Single | Tridem | Tandem | Tridem |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 700 | 1500 | 1200 | 2700 |

The code to create the `dataframe` is as follows:

```
weight=[700,1500,1200,2700]
name=['Single','Tridem','Tandem','Tridem']
ol_axle=pd.DataFrame([weight],columns=[name])
```

My apologies as the query doesn't appear to be that difficult, but what I want is that if there is 'Tridem' in column name, the column repeats two more times and the value is divided by 3 and if it there is 'Tandem' in col name, it repeats once more and the value is divided by 2 such that I get the resulting dataframe:

| Single | Tridem | Tridem | Tridem | Tandem | Tandem | Tridem | Tridem | Tridem |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 700 | 500 | 500 | 500 | 600 | 600 | 900 | 900 | 900 |

The code that I developed to get the required result is as follows:

```
# Initialize a flag to track whether division has been performed
tridem_divided = False
tandem_divided = False

# Iterate over the columns and update values based on conditions
for column in ol_axle.columns:
    if 'Tridem' in column and not tridem_divided:
        ol_axle[column] = ol_axle[column] / 3
        tridem_divided = True
    elif 'Tandem' in column and not tandem_divided:
        ol_axle[column] = ol_axle[column] / 2
        tandem_divided = True
    else:
        ol_axle[column] = ol_axle[column]
        
ol_axle
```

The issue is, that my code was working perfectly well and and I used it for a lot of data with various different combinations of these axle groups, but all of a sudden and for some reason I still do not know I started receiving the following error;

> PerformanceWarning: indexing past lexsort depth may impact
> performance.   ol_axle[column] = ol_axle[column] / 3

I just installed a `Matplotlib` and `OSMNX` library 2 days earlier and which I am sure has got nothing to do with this error popping up now.

I have tried other snippets but I am still getting this error.

I am not that experienced in Python as yet, so it would be great if anyone can help me get the results that I want for my `dataframe`.

Comment: My apologies. I have edited the question. Actually the code begins by extracting data from Excel file and then it creates that ol_axle dataframe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`numpy.repeat`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html) with [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.map.html):

```
n = {'Single': 1, 'Tandem': 2, 'Tridem': 3}
 
rep = ol_axle.columns.map(n)
    
out = (pd.DataFrame(np.repeat(ol_axle.div(rep, axis=1),
                              rep, axis=1),
                    columns=np.repeat(ol_axle.columns, rep),
                    index=ol_axle.index)
       )

print(out)
```

Variant of @Timeless' approach using [`iloc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html):

```
n = {'Single': 1, 'Tandem': 2, 'Tridem': 3}

rep = ol_axle.columns.map(n)

out = (ol_axle.div(rep)
       .iloc[:, np.repeat(np.arange(ol_axle.shape[1]), rep)]
       )
```

Output:

```
   Single  Tridem  Tridem  Tridem  Tandem  Tandem  Tridem  Tridem  Tridem
0   700.0   500.0   500.0   500.0   600.0   600.0   900.0   900.0   900.0
```

Answer (score 2):

> *The issue is that my code **was working** perfectly well..*

Are you sure ? Because the code your provided doesn't appear to be inserting columns.

That being said, here is a *no-loop* proposition with [`div`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.div.html#)/[`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) & [`repeat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.repeat.html) :

```
reps = {"Tandem": 2, "Tridem": 3} # +more if needed

rng = range(ol_axle.shape[1]); ser = pd.Series(ol_axle.columns)

out = (
    ol_axle.set_axis(rng, axis=1).div(ser.map(reps).fillna(1))
      .loc[:, pd.Index(rng).repeat(ser.map(reps).fillna(1))]
      .rename(columns=ser).convert_dtypes()
)
```

| Single | Tridem | Tridem | Tridem | Tandem | Tandem | Tridem | Tridem | Tridem |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 700 | 500 | 500 | 500 | 600 | 600 | 900 | 900 | 900 |

Used input :

```
ol_axle = pd.DataFrame(
    data=[[700, 1500, 1200, 2700]],
    columns=["Single", "Tridem", "Tandem", "Tridem"],
)
```

Comment: Why not using `iloc` instead of swapping for a range index? That said I prefer using raw numpy ;)

Comment: @mozway, your feedback is always inspiring ;) I was about to update my answer (*after that*) with the code below but you were faster ;) `reps = ol_axle.columns.map({"Tandem": 2, "Tridem": 3}).fillna(1); out = (ol_axle.div(reps, axis=1).iloc[:, pd.Index(range(ol_axle.shape[1])).repeat(reps)].convert_dtypes())`.

Comment: Oops I thought you were AFK, which is why I posted the variant

Comment: I was indeed, but no worries. It was your idea after all ;)

Comment: Thanks so much @mozway for your response. Your suggestion is working perfectly well. Really appreciate your support.

Comment: I would like to thank @Timeless as well. Your contribution is greatly appreciated.  Deeply grateful for your expertise!

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution, which uses [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) to concatenate the successive sub-dataframes to create the final dataframe:

```
cols = ['Tridem','Tandem']
z = lambda y: 3 if y == 'Tridem' else 2
pd.concat(
    [ol_axle['Single']] + 
    [pd.concat([ol_axle[x]] * z(x), axis=1).div(z(x)) for x in cols],
    axis=1)
```

Output:

```
  Single Tridem Tridem Tridem Tridem Tridem Tridem Tandem Tandem
0    700  500.0  900.0  500.0  900.0  500.0  900.0  600.0  600.0
```